# How to index a calculated hash column

Tags: sql-server, view, unique-constraint, udf

In SQL Server, I have created a view that contains two columns. a normal column and a calculated hash column. I need to create a unique constraint on these two columns. Trying to add a constraint or index causes an error because of the GetHash UDF.

```
CREATE VIEW HashView
WITH SCHEMABINDING    
AS
SELECT p.ItemId, [dbo].[GetHash](p.Id) as PriceHash from dbo.price p
```

Is there a simple way to solve this or do I need to resort to using a trigger?

Comment: what's the function do? the same thing as [`HASHBYTES()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is not willing to trust you that your CLR function is deterministic.  And so only allows CLR computed columns to be indexed if persisted.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that this might be the case. I will use a trigger to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

make your view like this,

```
CREATE VIEW HashView
WITH SCHEMABINDING    
AS
SELECT p.ItemId,p.Id, [dbo].[GetHash](p.Id) as PriceHash from dbo.price p
```

then create unique composite constraint on itemid and id as usual

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_HashView ON dbo.HashView(itemid,id)
GO
```